# IOException on move file (FileUtils.moveFile)

Tags: java

I'm getting an IOException that is caught while trying to move a file.

```
    public static void moveFile() {
        String filePath = "C:/Users/newuser/inbound";  

        String archiveFolder = filePath.replaceAll("inbound", "archive");

        File critLocation = new File(archiveFolder.concat("/crit"));

        File sourceFolder = new File(filePath);
        File[] listOfFiles = sourceFolder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {

            if (file.getName().contains("crit")){
                System.out.println("Moving crit file... " + file.getName());
                try {
                    FileUtils.moveFile(file, critLocation);
                } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
                    System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " already exists.");
                    file.delete();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    System.out.println("AN IO EXCEPTION HAS OCCURED");
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

I just want to use a filePath to move some files around. I also tried

```
FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(file, sitLocation, false);
```

but to no avail.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: I am getting the sysout line System.out.println("AN IO EXCEPTION HAS OCCURED"); on my console.

Comment: what is the real exception that is being thrown? Try at least `exception.printStackTrace()`

Comment: AH, I see now, it is saying file already exists in the stack trace

Comment: Remove `System.out.println("AN IO EXCEPTION HAS OCCURED");` and let the method throw `IOException`, cause you're just shooting yourself in the leg replacing the real exception with some useless message.

Comment: OK what fixed it is using moveFileToDIrectory... not sure why it wasn't working before... anyways, thanks for the help